# react-scripts don't work after src/ directory renamed

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack, react-scripts

I renamed `src/` to `frontend/` and after this I have it searching in old folder `src/`:

```
$ npm run build

> passport_client_dfinity@0.1.0 build
> react-scripts build

Could not find a required file.
  Name: index.js
  Searched in: /home/porton/Projects/passport_client_dfinity/src
```

despite I have created `webpack.config.js`:

```
const path = require('path');

// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
    entry: './frontend/index.js',
    resolve: {
        modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'frontend'), 'node_modules'],
    },
};
```

Here is `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "passport_client_dfinity",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@dfinity/agent": "^0.20.2",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.70",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.47",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.18",
    "@web3-onboard/core": "^2.21.2",
    "@web3-onboard/injected-wallets": "^2.10.11",
    "@web3-onboard/react": "^2.8.13",
    "@web3-onboard/walletconnect": "^2.5.3",
    "bootstrap": "^5.3.2",
    "ethers": "^6.10.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.9.2",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-spinners": "^0.13.8",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "backend": "dfx deploy backend && env -i scripts/read-env.sh",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "sources": "mops sources"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "os": false,
    "path": false
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: `react-scripts` (which I assume you are using as part of `create-react-app`) does not support custom webpack configuration. Note: this is a heavy limitation on any project with relatively lightweight complexity. If you reach the edges of `create-react-app`, its probably time to move on from it. There are also big questions about its future anyway, as it's pretty much an abandoned project.

Comment: If this is an old project and you don't have the time or inclination to migrate to something modern like Vite, you can either "eject" (see create react app docs) and edit the webpack config there, or you could use community solutions like https://craco.js.org/docs/.